# LeetCode's "The Maze II" problem: why does this solution exceed the time limit?

Tags: python, algorithm, heap, shortest-path, dijkstra

I'm trying to solve LeetCode's [The Maze II](https://leetcode.com/problems/the-maze-ii/) problem,

[image]
[image]
[image]

but I'm running into a 'Time Limit Exceeded' failed test:

[image]

My approach is to use Dijkstra's algorithm with a min-priority queue, similar to what is described here (https://leetcode.com/problems/the-maze-ii/discuss/351244/Python3-heapq-priority-queue-beats-100), so I'm a bit stumped why my solution is timing out.

Here is my attempted solution:

```
import collections
import heapq
from typing import List, Tuple, Callable, Optional, Dict, Set


class Solution:
    def shortestDistance(self, maze: List[List[int]], start: List[int], destination: List[int]) -> int:
        return shortest_distance(
            maze=maze, start=tuple(start), destination=tuple(destination))


def shortest_distance(maze: List[List[int]], start: Tuple[int, int], destination: Tuple[int, int]) -> int:
    distances: Dict[Tuple[int, int], int] = collections.defaultdict(lambda: float('inf'))
    distances[start] = 0

    heap = [(0, start)]
    visited: Set[Tuple[int, int]] = {start}

    while heap:
        distance, coord = heapq.heappop(heap)
        visited.add(coord)

        if coord == destination:
            return distance

        for neighbor, d in get_neighbors(coord, maze):
            distances[neighbor] = min(distances[neighbor], distances[coord] + d)
            if neighbor not in visited:
                heapq.heappush(heap, (distances[neighbor], neighbor))

    return -1


DIRECTIONS: List[Callable[[Tuple[int, int]], Tuple[int, int]]] = [
    lambda coord: (coord[0] - 1, coord[1]),     # up
    lambda coord: (coord[0] + 1, coord[1]),     # down
    lambda coord: (coord[0], coord[1] - 1),     # left
    lambda coord: (coord[0], coord[1] + 1),     # right
]


def get_neighbors(coord: Tuple[int, int], maze: List[List[int]]) -> List[Tuple[Tuple[int, int], int]]:
    return [tup for tup in [
        get_neighbor(coord, maze, direction) for direction in DIRECTIONS]
        if tup[0] is not None]


def get_neighbor(
        coord: Tuple[int, int],
        maze: List[List[int]],
        direction: Callable[[Tuple[int, int]], Tuple[int, int]]) -> Tuple[Optional[Tuple[int, int]], int]:
    dist = -1
    prev, curr = None, coord
    while valid(curr, maze):
        prev, curr = curr, direction(curr)
        dist += 1
    return (prev, dist) if prev != coord else (None, -1)


def valid(coord: Tuple[int, int], maze: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
    return in_bounds(coord, maze) and maze[coord[0]][coord[1]] == 0


def in_bounds(coord: Tuple[int, int], maze: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
    return 0 <= coord[0] < len(maze) and 0 <= coord[1] < len(maze[0])
```

As I understand it, the time complexity of pushing a node onto the heap is `O(log N)`, and since this happens once for each node in the graph, I would expect the total time complexity to be `O(N log N)`, which it would seem should be an 'efficient' solution.

Is there some inefficiency in this algorithm that I overlooked?

Comment: Is this a premium problem? I cannot see it

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Added the problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that each coordinate tuple gets pushed only once to your queue may not be right. You might push the same position twice if you come at it from two different neighboring positions before it's been accessed itself.

Bad ASCII-art diagram:

```
A B
B C D
```

If you start at the `A` position, you'll add its two neighbors, the two `B` positions, to the queue as you process `A`. You'll then process *both* of the `B` nodes before you process their mutual neighbor, `C`. Because each of the `B` positions add their neighbors to the queue, `C` will be added twice. That duplication will continue, as each time you process `C`, you'll add its neighbor `D` to the heap.

A generic version of Dijkstra's algorithm can't easily avoid positions from being put into the queue multiple times (because a new path to a node might be shorter than one you've pushed but not explored yet, and there's no easy way to lookup and modify values in a heap). But you can prevent one instance of repetition from perpetuating itself. Just refuse to process any position that has already been visited:

```
visited: Set[Tuple[int, int]] = set()        # this set needs to start empty now

while heap:
    distance, coord = heapq.heappop(heap)
    if coord in visited:                     # skip repeat visits
        continue
    visited.add(coord)
```

I'd also note that your code probably has another issue (unrelated to performance). They way you're generating neighbors, you're will only ever change direction when a current path dead-ends. For example, I don't think you can solve this maze (where you're trying to go from `S` to `E`, with the `.`s being the maze's open spaces:

```
S . . 
  E
```

Your neighbor code will tell you that `S`'s only neighbor is the rightmost dot and that position's only neighbor will be `S` (which you've already visited). You'll never stop in the middle of the top row, so that you can change direction to go down to the exit.

Comment: Indeed after adding the `if coord in visited: continue` optimization all the tests passed on LeetCode. Regarding your second point, this is part of of the problem statement: "There is a ball in a maze with empty spaces and walls. The ball can go through empty spaces by rolling up, down, left or right, but it won't stop rolling until hitting a wall. When the ball stops, it could choose the next direction.". I realize that the question might only be visible to LeetCode Premium members; I'll add details to the question for future reference.

Comment: Ah, OK, it sounds like you were matching the maze rules correctly then. Sorry I jumped to the conclusion you were doing it wrong! I just thought it might have been an optimization (versus going square by square) that had lead you astray.